# Regex to remove anything that's not numeric or specific words

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a mathematical algorithm creator where the user inserts variables from a list of possible variables and they can create an algorithm with only those variables and numbers and characters used in math like parenthesis and others.
I need a regular expression that will remove from the string anything that is not either one of these variables or ().*-+/ or a number.
I've tried many regular expressions but none have done what I need
all the variables must be surrounded by curly brackets.

For example

```
/^(?!{profitPercent}|{productPrice}|{weight}|{quantityInCart}|{lineTotal}|{cartTotal}|{billingUnits}|{test_111}|{test_213}|{test_prod_input_15}|{test_prod_input_16}).*/g
```

This just removes everything, and it doesn't have the exception for numbers and ().*-+/

Say I have the following string:

```
var str='this is a string with a {productPrice} variable and some 827/100 math in it';
```

I need to remove everything except

```
{productPrice}827/100
```

This is my code:

```
var reg=new RegExp("^(?!{" + escapeString(variableNames.join("}|{")) + "}).*","g");
txt=txt.replace(reg,'');
```

I've tried many many different expressions, none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stead of asserting the start of the string `^` and using the variables in a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!` you can use them in a non capturing group `(?:`

Then add the variables you want to match to a character class `[().*+/\d]+` and add that to the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

This will give you the matches that you want to keep, and you can use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) using an empty string as the delimiter to concatenate them, resulting in:

`{productPrice}827/100`

Your code (you have to add `escapeString`) could look like:

```js
var variableNames = [
  "profitPercent",
  "productPrice",
  "weight",
  "quantityInCart",
  "lineTotal",
  "cartTotal",
  "billingUnits",
  "test_111",
  "test_213",
  "test_prod_input_15",
  "test_prod_input_16"
];

var str = 'this is a string with a {productPrice} variable and some 827/100 math in it';
var reg = new RegExp("(?:{" + variableNames.join("}|{") + "}|[\\d)(.*+/]+)", "g");
str = str.match(reg).join('');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: thanks this worked. i'm now trying to apply the same regex in php using preg_replace to do the same thing as this. i'm using preg_replace('/(?:{'.implode('}|{',array_column($vars,'name')).'}|[\\d0-9'.preg_quote(implode('',$chars)).'\/]+)/','',$algo); but it's returning the text that i do not want. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: @SuzanneEdelman You are using preg_replace but I think you could use preg_match_all, for example https://3v4l.org/9vfD7

Answer (score 3):

I will do it selecting the desired value using match

```
{[^}]+}|[\d)(.*+/]+
```

- `{[^}]+}` - Matches `{` followed by anything `}`.
- `|` - Alternation.
- `[[\d)(.*+/]+]` - Matches `digit, operators, (, )`

```js
let str = `var str='this is a string with a {productPrice} variable and some 827/100 math in it`

let op = str.match(/{[^}]+}|[\d)(.*+/]+/g)

console.log(op.join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier if you split up the string first i.e.

```js
const whitelist = new Set([
  '{profitPercent}',
  '{productPrice}',
  '{weight}',
  '{quantityInCart}',
  '{lineTotal}',
  '{cartTotal}',
  '{billingUnits}',
  '{test_111}',
  '{test_213}',
  '{test_prod_input_15}',
  '{test_prod_input_16}',
])

const regex = /[0-9.*\-+\/]/;
const str = 'this is a string with a {productPrice} variable and some 827/100 math in it'

const newStr = str.split(' ').filter((word) => {
  return whitelist.has(word) || regex.test(word)
}).join('')

console.log(newStr)
```

I'd pick the other answer if you don't have a whitelist of variables and just need to match anything inside braces

Answer (score 0):

Can be done like this.

`/.*?(?:((?:{profitPercent}|{productPrice}|{weight}|{quantityInCart}|{lineTotal}|{cartTotal}|{billingUnits}|{test_111}|{test_213}|{test_prod_input_15}|{test_prod_input_16}|[-().*+\d\/])+)|$)/g`

https://regex101.com/r/lHx4FE/1

Instead of deleting what you *DON'T* want, delete all but what you *DO* want.
The positive interpretation is always better.

Replace with `$1` the stuff you want.

Expanded

```
 .*? 
 (?:
      (                             # (1 start)
           (?:
                {profitPercent}
             |  {productPrice}
             |  {weight}
             |  {quantityInCart}
             |  {lineTotal}
             |  {cartTotal}
             |  {billingUnits}
             |  {test_111}
             |  {test_213}
             |  {test_prod_input_15}
             |  {test_prod_input_16}
             |  [-().*+\d/] 
           )+
      )                             # (1 end)
   |  
      $ 
 )
```